# API manager-Call Mediator - Synapse encountered an exception, No error handlers found

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, wso2-esb

I have simple call mediator defined in my api-manager sequence. but it is failing with error - **Synapse encountered an exception, No error handlers found - [Message Dropped]**

```
HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-1 >> "[\r][\n]"{org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire}
HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-1 >> "[\n]" {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire}
HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-1 >> "        {"Message":"Hello World ! All Ok.."}[\n]" {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire}
HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-1 >> "    " {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire}
ERROR {org.apache.synapse.continuation.ContinuationStackManager} -  Resource : null not found {org.apache.synapse.continuation.ContinuationStackManager}
ERROR {org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.SynapseCallbackReceiver} -  Synapse encountered an exception, No error handlers found - [Message Dropped]
Resource : null not found {org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.SynapseCallbackReceiver}
```

My sequence is as below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<sequence name="call_mediator_test_in" trace="disable" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
    <call>
        <endpoint>
            <http method="get" uri-template="https://localhost:8243/inq/v2.0/abcd/100"/>
        </endpoint>
    </call>
    <respond/>
</sequence>
```

Please advise what is wrong. How to add error handlers ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In APIM 1.10.0, this is [a known issue](https://wso2.org/jira/browse/APIMANAGER-4242).

In APIM 2.0.0, you should use call mediator in blocking mode.

```
<call blocking="true">
```

Comment: You are awesome @Bhathiya. you have saved my days ! it worked like charm... thanks a lot.